# AMP and Paypal form CORS issue

Tags: forms, mobile

I'm having an issue to use the Paypal "buy now" button on AMP pages (it's working on non AMP pages)

I'm using this button (code from Paypal website) :

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input name="charset" type="hidden" value="UTF-8"> <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick">
<input name="business" type="hidden" value="email">
<input name="undefined_quantity" type="hidden" value="1">
<input name="item_name" type="hidden" value="text">
<input name="amount" type="hidden" value="30.00">
<input name="shipping" type="hidden" value="0.00">
<input name="shipping2" type="hidden" value="0.00">
<input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="EUR">
<input name="lc" type="hidden" value="FR">
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="no-padding">
<img src="https://www.paypal.com/fr_FR/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif">
</button>
<img src="https://www.paypal.com/fr_FR/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="text" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

And the error is :

```
Access to fetch at 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?_wp_amp_action_xhr_converted=1&__amp_source_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwebsiteurl' from origin 'https://websiteurl' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?_wp_amp_action_xhr_converted=1&__amp_source_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwebsiteurl:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
log.js:258 [amp-form] Form submission failed: Error: XHR Failed fetching (https://www.paypal.com/...): Failed to fetch​​​
    at bb (https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js:29:169)
    at Ya.f.createExpectedError (https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js:24:235)
    at https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js:142:154
```

I've checked on the amp documentation regarding core issue [here](https://amp.dev/fr/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-caches-and-cors/amp-cors-requests/?format=websites#verify-cors-header) I've understand the main issue but I'm unable to solve it, I've tried to add this to my .htaccess but same issue :

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'https://cdn.ampproject.org​'
Header set AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin 'https://your-domain.com'
```

Comment: Just coming across this now. I work on the official AMP plugin for WordPress. We've been tracking similar issues to this like https://github.com/ampproject/amp-wp/issues/4191 and we've got a solution that may be able to solve this. We'll include this in the test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Existing forms with the `post` method can be problematic to adapt to AMP especially when they are pointing to an external domain. There are two issues:

- Forms in AMP with the `post` action are expected to be requesting JSON data to display in the form without causing a page navigation. When page navigation is desired, then the server is supposed to send an `AMP-Redirect-To` response header. Naturally this is not going to help for PayPal.
- There isn't an ability to set the response headers on a remote server (e.g. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`).

I work on the official AMP plugin for WordPress and we have an [issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amp-wp/issues/4191) open to try to automatically convert such forms, by introducing a [local form proxy](https://github.com/ampproject/amp-wp/pull/4212).

Nevertheless, there are two workarounds you can try.

### Switch to `get` method on `form`

While this doesn't work in all cases, sometimes form submission handlers accept `GET` requests just the same as `POST`. Here's how that can look in AMP:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="get" target="_top">
    <input name="charset" type="hidden" value="UTF-8">
    <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick">
    <input name="business" type="hidden" value="email">
    <input name="undefined_quantity" type="hidden" value="1">
    <input name="item_name" type="hidden" value="text">
    <input name="amount" type="hidden" value="30.00">
    <input name="shipping" type="hidden" value="0.00">
    <input name="shipping2" type="hidden" value="0.00">
    <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="EUR">
    <input name="lc" type="hidden" value="FR">
    <input type="hidden" name="submit">
    <button type="submit" class="no-padding">
        <amp-img src="https://www.paypal.com/fr_FR/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" width="93" height="26" alt="Acheter"></amp-img>
    </button>
    <amp-pixel src="https://www.paypal.com/fr_FR/i/scr/pixel.gif"></amp-pixel>
</form>
```

### Use an `amp-iframe`

If using the `get` method doesn't work, then another a workaround you can use is to wrap the the `form` in an `amp-iframe`:

```
<amp-iframe width="93" height="26" sandbox="allow-forms allow-top-navigation" srcdoc='
    <style>
        html,body { margin:0; padding: 0; }
    </style>
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
        <input name="charset" type="hidden" value="UTF-8">
        <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick">
        <input name="business" type="hidden" value="email">
        <input name="undefined_quantity" type="hidden" value="1">
        <input name="item_name" type="hidden" value="text">
        <input name="amount" type="hidden" value="30.00">
        <input name="shipping" type="hidden" value="0.00">
        <input name="shipping2" type="hidden" value="0.00">
        <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="EUR">
        <input name="lc" type="hidden" value="FR">
        <input type="image" name="submit" src="https://www.paypal.com/fr_FR/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif">
        <img src="https://www.paypal.com/fr_FR/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="text" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
'>
    <span placeholder>Loading…</span>
</amp-iframe>
```

---

Please let me know if either of these work for you.